# What does this in the MOTD for an MC server mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

Random text? What could it mean? I'm actually referring to specifically the random text. Any idea what it could represent?

Comment: From top to bottom: What it is (a Minecraft Server), Ping (on the right in green), the GUID (= Globally Unique ID. What of? No idea), Version number (on the right, overlapping the GUID), the URL of the server, a message, and lastly a logo(?)

Comment: From top to bottom (more accurate): the name you've given it, the ping (the greener it is the better), random text (what you are referring to), and the "scanning for local games" text with loading circles.

Answer (score 6):

What it does is allows certain websites like minecraft forums and stuff like that recognise that it is your server. You are generally given a MOTD that is unique when you try and register your server. IF it is your server, you are able to easily change the MOTD temporarily and allow the site you are registering your server with to verify that it is actually yours. Once the activation completed, you can change it back to what ever you like.

Comment: So someone has just left their activation code on. Not a ringing endorsement of the server admins.

Comment: Yes, generally if there is random numbers like that, they are simply doing something to recognise their server on websites or something like that